# Variable as a YAML tree. How to save indent?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have `yml` file with template. Template is a part of keys started from a middle of yml tree.

Templating works is ok, but indent is saved only for last key. How to save indent for all keys?

`base.yml`:

```
app:
  config1:
    base: {{ service1.company.backend | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
  config2:
    node: {{ service1.company.addr | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
```

`config.yml`:

```
service1:
  company:
    backend:
      node1: "xxx"
      node2: "yyy"
      node3: "zzz"
    addr:
      street: ""
```

I need to get:

```
app:
  config1:
    base:
      node1: "xxx"
      node2: "yyy"
      node3: "zzz"
  config2:
    node:
      street: ""
```

But really result is:

```
app:
  config1:
    base:
      node3: "zzz"
node1: "xxx"
node2: "yyy"
  config2:
    node:
      street: ""
```

`node1` and `node2` don't save an indent and Jinja2 parser gets the last node. On next step incorrect file is used in other role which doesn't handle it correctly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`indent` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#indent) in Jinja2 with appropriate indentation set (also `to_nice_yaml` produces a trailing newline character, so `trim` is necessary):

```
app:
  config1:
    base:
      {{ service1.company.backend | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | trim | indent(6) }}
  config2:
    node:
      {{ service1.company.addr | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | trim | indent(6) }}
```

---

Or create a helper variable and rely on Ansible `to_nice_yaml` filter for the whole value. For example:

```
...

vars:
  helper_var:
    app:
      config1:
        base: "{{ service1.company.backend }}"
      config2:
        node: "{{ service1.company.addr }}"

...

tasks:
  - copy:
      content: "{{ helper_var | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}"
      dest: my_file
```

Comment: Thank you! `indent` works very well but I think to use the helper variable more properly.

Comment: I like both methods. I wound up using the first, though, so I could limit what the user can change in the config file I'm creating.